# scopt "not found: value" defining val with same name

Tags: scala, sbt, scopt

For the following use of scopt:

```
import java.io.File

object Application extends App {

  case class Config(in: File = new File("."), out: File = new File("."), scripts: Seq[File] = Seq())

  val parser = new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("scopt") {
    head("Script Runner", "0.1")
    opt[File]('i', "in") required () valueName ("<path>") action { (x, c) =>
      c.copy(in = x)
    } text ("required in path property")
    opt[File]('o', "out") required () valueName ("<path>") action { (x, c) =>
      c.copy(out = x)
    } text ("required out path file property")
    arg[File]("<file>...") unbounded () required() action { (x, c) =>
      c.copy(scripts = c.scripts :+ x)
    } text ("unbounded script paths")
  }

  val config = parser.parse(args, Config())

  val scripts = config.map { argConfig => argConfig.scripts }

  config match {
    case Some(config) => println(config)
    case _ => println("config undefined")
  }
}
```

I get the compilation error:

```
[error] /Users/jamesclark/code/scratch/src/main/scala/Application.scala:13: not found: value x
[error]       c.copy(out = x)
```

If I rename either the `Config` parameter `scripts` or the val `scripts` then it compiles.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's happening here?
Is it a compiler issue, or am I missing some magic?

scala 2.11.8 / sbt 0.13.7 / scopt 3.5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the vals `parser`, `config` and `scripts` into `lazy val`s instead of `val`s gives the more helpful error message: `/src/main/scala/Application.scala:23: variable definition needs type because 'scripts' is used as a named argument in its body.`

Giving scripts its type annotation `val scripts: Option[Seq[File]] = ...` solves the issue.

Alternative ways to work around this are to rename either the `val scripts` or the `case class Config(... scripts: Seq[File] ...)` occurrences of `scripts`.

The root of the issue seems to come from the scopt library since moving the definition of the `parser` to a separate scope removes the need for any of the renaming or type annotation work arounds.

```
object Application extends App {

  def newParser(): OptionParser[Config] = {
    new scopt.OptionParser[Config]("scopt") {
      head("Script Runner", "0.1")

      opt[File]('i', "in") required () valueName ("<path>") action { (x, c) =>
        c.copy(in = x)
      } text ("required in path property")

      opt[File]('o', "out") required () valueName ("<path>") action { (x, c) =>
        c.copy(out = x)
      } text ("required out path file property")

      arg[File]("<file>...") unbounded () required() action { (x, c) =>
        c.copy(scripts = c.scripts :+ x)
      } text ("unbounded script paths")
    }
  }

  case class Config(in: File = new File("."), out: File = new File("."), scripts: Seq[File] = Seq())

  val parser = newParser()

  val config = parser.parse(args, Config())

  val scripts = config.map { argConfig => argConfig.scripts }

  config match {
    case Some(config) =>
      println(config)
    case _ =>
      println("config undefined")
  }
}
```